# Strange description 'StackOverflow.StackHtmlContent' in moderator action history

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, declined-flags

I recently declined a custom moderator flag with the reason

> Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of standard flags: see [What is Flagging?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)

This decline is visible in [my moderator action history](https://chess.stackexchange.com/admin/history/7297)* but the description is a little weird:

> Flag processed (PostOther, Declined, **StackOverflow.StackHtmlContent**) - Completely off-topic...

(emphasis mine). Screenshot:

[image]

Looks like a missing `ToString()` method to me.

*: that link 404s except for staff, for reproducing the issue

Comment: Strange, just tried it, but I only got "Flag processed (PostOther, Declined)" instead.